# Getting a lower z-index for a bigger number

Tags: javascript, css, math, z-index

This is more a maths question than a coding one... I'm creating a scatterplot with bubbles that also have different sizes. I want the bigger sizes to have a lower z-index than smaller sizes, to avoid the bigger ones standing over the smaller and making interaction impossible. So I need a formula revert that order by code. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the size and make it negative (`var zIndex = size * -1;`).

**Edit for a non-negative option.**

```
var zIndex = (1 / size) * 1000;
```

You can tweak the `1000` to your liking.  The reciprocal will give a smaller, but positive, floating point value for larger sizes (keeping it above zero).  The multiplication gives you a number you can work with.

Comment: I thinked of that, but that would give me negative z-index, and the bubbles will be behind other elements of the graphic I don't want them to be...

Comment: @ChiquiEsteban, I edited my answer to include a non-negative solution.

Comment: It's good to point out with the non-negative option that you should watch for `size === 0` since that would result in a division by zero exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of bubbles then you can just start by making the biggest one zero and the smallest one to the total number of bubbles. Alternatively, you could use negative Z-indicies.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth ...

From a performance point of view, the best approach is to calculate and apply each bubble's zIndex at the point of creation.

If that's impractical or impossible, then you can reindex all bubbles as follows :

```
function reindex_bubbles() {
    var bubbleArr = $(".bubble").get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.width() - a.width();//or possibly the other way round?
    });
    $.each(bubbleArr, function(i, bubble) {
        bubble.attr('zIndex', i);
    });
}
```

We assume here that `.width()` gives a reliable measure of the bubbles' sizes. If not, then substitute some other expression.